# How to prove an equation with $\ker$ and Im

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let f and g be two endomorphisms of E. How to prove that :
$$ f(\ker{g \circ f}) = \rm{Im}~f \cap \ker g~.$$

It is obvious that $\ker f \subset \ker{g \circ f} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in f(\ker{g\circ f})$. Then clearly $x\in\rm{Im}~f$. We know that there is some $y\in \ker{g\circ f}$ such that $x=f(y)$, so we have $g(x)=g(f(y))=0$, so $x\in\ker{g}$, whence $x\in \rm{Im}~f\cap \ker{g}$.

Similarly, let $x\in\rm{Im}~f\cap \ker{g}$. There exists $y$ such that $x=f(y)$ and in addition $g(x)=0$, so $g(f(y))=g(x)=0$, which means that $y\in \ker{g\circ f}$, so $x\in f(\ker{g\circ f})$.

Note that each inclusion is basically reversing the other, so you can simplify it to get both at once.

Answer (score 0):

(\subset) If $y =f(x)$ with $x \in \ker (g\circ f)$ then $y \in Im f$ and $0=g(f(x)) = g(y)$, so $y \in \ker g$.

(\supset) If $y \in Im f \cap \ker g$, then there exists $x\in E$ such that $ y = f(x) $ and $g (y) = 0$. So $ g(f(x) ) = g(y) =0 $ $\Longrightarrow$ $x \in \ker(g \circ f)$, this implies that $y \in f(\ker(g \circ f))$.